# Network redirection while using android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have been trying to understand the basics of android emulator networking. I found this [Emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#redirection) details.

which asks to execute these commands :

- telnet localhost 5554
- redir add tcp:5000:6000

Que : So my doubt is that where do I exactly enter these commands??

Comment: did u activate the telnet client on your pc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a normal command line window to type in `telnet localhost 5554`

you have to check first if telnet client is activated on your pc:

In windows:

check this link [turn-on-telnet-in-windows-7](http://www.lovemytool.com/blog/2010/03/turn-on-telnet-in-windows-7-by-tony-fortunato.html)

In ubuntu install it by:

```
$ sudo apt-get install telnet
```

You have to run your emulator first also!! hope this will help you

Comment: Thnx, it worked, I wasn't aware of telnet client activation. :)